# Getting value from an object with jQuery

Tags: jquery, json, object

I have this JSON, that I need to use.

```
{"services":{"344":{"post":{"ID":344}},"345":{"post":{"ID":345}}}}
```

I need to get the value of **services.344.post.ID** which is 344.
How can this be achieved?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If

```
var obj = JSON.parse('{"services":{"344":{"post":{"ID":344}},"345":{"post":{"ID":345}}}}');
```

Then you want `obj['services']['344']['post']['ID']`